# Custom Build Switch in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, configuration, build

I have created a customized build switch in a C#.net application, say "XYZ"

I want some piece of code to be executed only if the project is build in that mode.I know we can use

```
#if DEBUG
Console.WriteLine("Mode=Debug");
#else 
Console.WriteLine("Mode=Relase");
#endif
```

But my question is that can we do like the bellow???

```
 #if XYZ
 Console.WriteLine("Mode=Debug");
```

can anyone help me with the issue. some link..

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  (Just remember your #endif.)

Answer (score 1):

Set your custom build setting.  Right click on the project you want to modify, and select `properties`.

On the Build screen, look for "`Conditional compilation symbols`".  Enter "`XYZ`", or whatever in there.  That setting is per-project, per build setting.

Comment: Oh, and for great fun, enter `FALSE` as your conditional statement.  Write appropriate code for giggles.